# Is it acceptable to promote sites still in Area51 in answers and/or comments?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, area-51

As Stack Overflow topics grow and diverse, people start suggesting and helping in the creation of new sites in the Exchange Network. For this purpose, the [Area51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) exists. It acts as a platform to group people interested in participate in new sites focused on new or specific topics.

However, many people don't know the existence of Area51 and could be potentially interested in the creation of new sites. I wonder if, far from spamming, **it is accepted to suggest in comments or/and answers the support of new sites still in early stages of their creation**. For example, a DevOps community could get a lot of support from people among the Stack Overflow community, and the recommendation of joining its building process can be pertinent in many posts.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96910/promote-area-51-proposal-on-other-se-sites

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaning towards leaving a comment on the OP question only if the question is not quite following SO guidelines in the first place (being too broad, opinion seeking questions, etc). Otherwise, SO questions will be diluted in a sea of promotion, and I definitely do not look forward to that...

Furthermore, the promotional comment on this type of question (as long as the question itself is not deleted) should attract enough people (including recent folks like myself) to know more about other communities while also getting more acquainted with SO guidelines. Also, I remember seeing a few questions that were moved to other communities, so this would also help in transitioning content when the new communities are greenlit (if they have not done so already.)

Comment: You have a really good point @Deovandski. I stated that seek for support for new communities "can be pertinent in many posts". You are providing one example of when it may be pertinent: "In questions of new starters that might not be suitable for SO but could be moved to other sites". Many thanks.